# Trigger (dispatchEvent) the 'onerror' with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my code I did: `element.onerror = my_function;`

I am wondering how to forcefully trigger this event so I can test it?

Can someone show me how to use the `dispatchEvent` flow to do this?

Comment: `element.onerror()` will be the easiest.

Comment: Duh, of course, element.onerror() is nice. Was wondering how to get it working with dispatchEvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OKAY I figured it out!

```
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('error', false, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I figured out that `onerror` is an 'HTMLEvents' according to google.
Since the event name is `error`, the event is `error`, and I knew that `error` doesn't bubble, hence the `false` in the second parameter of `initEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/EventTarget.dispatchEvent).

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. What to pass into createEvent, initEvent... etc. Do you mind showing me how?